# WorkManager startWork() never calls when constraints are met

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I want to WorkManager startWork() to be called every time the user connects to the internet through wifi or 3g/4g/5g.

It calls only one time at the start where I register it.

> enqueuing work when a user signs in.

```
Worker.startWorkManager(SignInActivity.this);
startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this,UsersActivity.class);
```

it never calls again whenever the user turns Wifi OFF and ON again regardless app is in foreground or background or app is killed through swiped from recent apps.

I want it to be called every time user turned Wifi OFF and ON in every scenario i.e foreground, background, or app is killed.

**Worker.class**

```
public class Worker {
    public Worker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    }

    public static void startWorkManager(Context context) {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(Constants.TAG_SYNC_DATA, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncDataWorker.class)
                .addTag(Constants.TAG_SYNC_DATA)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build());
    }
}
```

**SyncDataWorker.class**

```
public class SyncDataWorker extends ListenableWorker {


    public SyncDataWorker(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
            AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    completer.setException(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    completer.set(Result.success());
                }

                @Override
                public void onRetry() {
                    completer.set(Result.retry());
                }
            };
            new AsyncSyncData(getApplicationContext(), callback).execute();
            return callback;
        });
    }
}
```

**AsyncSynData.class**

```
public class AsyncSyncData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final Context context;

    ArrayList<message> messageArrayListNotSync;
    ArrayList<unread_messages> unreadMessagesArrayList;

    String user_id = "";
    private AsyncCallback callback = null;

    public AsyncSyncData(Context context, AsyncCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        messageArrayListNotSync = new ArrayList<>();
        unreadMessagesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context);
        user user = null;
        ArrayList<user> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>(db.applicationDao().getAllUsers());
        if (userArrayList.size() > 0) {
            user = userArrayList.get(0);
        }
        messageArrayListNotSync = new ArrayList<>(db.applicationDao().getAllMessagesNotSync(!user_id.isEmpty() ? user_id : user.threadId));
        unreadMessagesArrayList = new ArrayList<>(db.applicationDao().getUnreadMessageStatus());

        System.out.println("messageArrayListNotSync: " + messageArrayListNotSync);
        System.out.println("unreadMessagesArrayList: " + unreadMessagesArrayList);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("user_id", !user_id.isEmpty() ? user_id : user.threadId);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            JsonArray json_messages = gson.toJsonTree(messageArrayListNotSync).getAsJsonArray();
            JsonArray json_unread_messages = gson.toJsonTree(unreadMessagesArrayList).getAsJsonArray();

            jsonObject.put("messages", json_messages);
            jsonObject.put("unread_messages", json_unread_messages);


            RequestHandler.postRequest("/messages", jsonObject, context, new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
                   
                    final JSONObject finalResult = result;
                    try {
                        if (result != null && result.has("success") && result.getBoolean("success")) {
                            new AsyncDeleteUnreadMessagesList(context, unreadMessagesArrayList, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCallbackCompleted() {
                                    try {
                                        ArrayList<com.app.amber.internet.DATABASE_OPERATIONS.schema.message> messagesToStore = new ArrayList<>();
                                        JSONObject result = finalResult.getJSONObject("data");

                                        JSONObject last_messages = result.getJSONObject("last_messages");

                                        new AsyncUpdateLastMessage(context, last_messages, true, new Callback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCallbackCompleted() {
                                                try {
                                                    JSONArray json_messages_to_store = result.getJSONArray("messages");
                                                    JSONArray json_evetns_type_1 = result.getJSONArray("eventsType1");
                                                    JSONArray json_evetns_type_2 = result.getJSONArray("eventsType2");

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < json_messages_to_store.length(); i++) {
                                                        JSONObject data = json_messages_to_store.getJSONObject(i);

                                                        String id = data.getString("id"),
                                                                sender_id = data.getString("sender_id"),
                                                                receiver_id = data.getString("receiver_id"),
                                                                msg = data.getString("msg"),
                                                                type = data.getString("type"),
                                                                path = data.getString("path"),
                                                                download_status = data.getString("download"),
                                                                group_users = data.getString("group_users"),
                                                                group_message_status = data.getString("group_message_status");

                                                        boolean is_sender = false;

                                                        long data_created = data.getLong("date_created");

                                                        int is_read = 0;

                                                        com.app.amber.internet.DATABASE_OPERATIONS.schema.message message =
                                                                new com.app.amber.internet.DATABASE_OPERATIONS.schema.message(id, sender_id, receiver_id, msg, type, path, is_sender, data_created,
                                                                        is_read, download_status, sender_id, group_users, group_message_status);
                                                        messagesToStore.add(message);
                                                    }

                                                    ArrayList<String> messageIdsType1 = new ArrayList<>();
                                                    ArrayList<String> messageIdsType2 = new ArrayList<>();

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < json_evetns_type_1.length(); i++) {
                                                        messageIdsType1.add(json_evetns_type_1.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                                                    }

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < json_evetns_type_2.length(); i++) {
                                                        messageIdsType2.add(json_evetns_type_2.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                                                    }

                                                    new AsyncStoreOldMessagesLocally(context, messagesToStore, new Callback() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCallbackCompleted() {

                                                            new AsyncUpdateMessageStatus(context, messageIdsType1, 1, new Callback() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onCallbackCompleted() {

                                                                    new AsyncUpdateMessageStatus(context, messageIdsType2, 2, new Callback() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onCallbackCompleted() {

                                                                            new AsyncUpdateMessageStatusList(context, messageArrayListNotSync, new Callback() {
                                                                                @Override
                                                                                public void onCallbackCompleted() {
                                                                                    sendCallBack();
                                                                                }
                                                                            }).execute();
                                                                        }
                                                                    }).execute();
                                                                }
                                                            }).execute();
                                                        }
                                                    }).execute();
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    System.out.println("Exception occurred while getting data from data JSONObject received from service: " + e.toString());
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                    sendCallBack();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }).execute();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        System.out.println("Exception occurred while parsing data JSONObject received from service: " + e.toString());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        sendCallBack();
                                    }
                                }
                            }).execute();
                        } else {
                            sendCallBack();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception occurred while parsing webservice result: " + e.toString());
                        sendCallBack();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception occurred while parsing messaging lists: " + e.toString());
            sendCallBack();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void sendCallBack() {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onSuccess();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**"WorkManager startWork() never calls when constraints are met"**
**"It calls only one time at the start where I register it."**

The **ListenableWorker** can be **recreated** in some situations, **a new instance of ListenableWorker** with the **same first ListenableWorker.id**. But for it be recreated, **it can't be finished**. Here are some situations:

1. Some of the constraints do not matches anymore and it matches again
2. System was rebooted

Now here are some situations where it will be finished:

1. Some Exception was raised without treatment
2. completer.set(Result.success()) was called
3. completer.set(Result.failure()) was called

There are some situations in your code that the worker can be finished.

1. There are **lots** of calls to **AsyncSyncData.sendCallBack**, which can causes the call of **completer.set(Result.success()) on the ListenableWorker instance.** If it happens the ListenableWorker completes the job, so it will not be recreated anymore.

**"I want to WorkManager startWork() to be called every time the user connects to the internet through wifi or 3g/4g/5g."**

The **WorkManager alone won't create a new instance of the ListenableWork every time the user connects to Internet.** The [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is a API to schedule tasks, and the constraints defined in the ListenableWork are used to not start it while them are not matched, after the ListenableWork finishes, how was discussed above, this task is finished, so no more to do.

If you want to listen to some connectivity changes, you should use **[ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager)** and then when the user connects to, you do what you want. [Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.net.ConnectivityManager&method=registerNetworkCallback) are some examples that could help you
to do it.